# NDSolve Unable to Produce Solution for Second-Order Differential Equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Below is the equation that I am trying to solve and ultimately plot:
$$y''+5y'+6y=e^{-3x}; \;y(0)=-\frac{1}{2}, \; y'(0)=0, \; x \in [0,2]$$

To solve this on Mathematica, I followed its help page and typed the following code:

`s = NDSolve[{y''[x] + 5y'[x] + 6y[x] == e^-3x, y[0]==-1/2, y'[0]==0},y,{x}  ∈  {0,2}]`

However, after typing it, Mathematica simply redisplayed my given equation and problem in a different "format" - not bothering to produce the solution to the problem or even the interpolating function which I frequently see on the Mathematica help page.

In addition, note that I also did try to write the below code as a substitute for the above seemingly ineffective one:

`s = NDSolve[{y''[x] + 5y'[x] + 6y[x] == e^-3x, y[0] == -1/2, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x,0,2}]`

However, Mathematica began spewing out a weird error about the function value, which I have no idea what is going on.

In short, my goal is to first generate a numerical solution to the given equation. Afterward, I hope to plot my solution given by Mathematica in a y(x) vs. x form.

I think I'm getting close to accomplishing that. However, after trying a long time to figure out why this piece of code isn't working, I am hoping the community could provide me any degree of insight toward the matter. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: hi, unless there is specific reason to use  `NDSolve`, you can just use `DSolve` here as this has exact solution. $-\frac{1}{2} e^{-3 x} \left(2 x+e^x\right)$

Comment: @Nasser, Thank you for your help! I decided to use NDSolve simply because I wanted to get the numerical solution (i.e. the interpolating function) and then take the solution(s) and plot it.

Having done that, I am trying to get the closed form (symbolic) solution with DSolve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Mathematica, the fundamental constant $e$ is written `E`. Thus you can write either `E^(-3)` or `Exp[-3]` for $e^{-3}$. In your code, Mathematica will understand `e` as an unknown variable, not the constant you want, and therefore cannot solve the system. Try this instead:

```
s = NDSolve[{y''[x] + 5 y'[x] + 6 y[x] == Exp[-3x], y[0] == -1/2, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: Judging from the OP's TeX, I'd suggest `Exp[-3x]` is what is wanted.

Comment: My bad; thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! The simple change managed to do the trick.